# C# button click datafrom textboxes to a data grid view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

The following method is used by me to transfer data from 3 text boxes(as a single row) to a data grid view(dataGridView2) when a button is clicked:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    f1.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
    dt1.Columns.Add("MessageID", typeof(string));
    dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt1.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));
    DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
    dr["MessageID"] = IDtext.Text;
    dr["Name"] = nameText.Text;
    dr["Number"] = numberText.Text;
    f1.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
}
```

But when I click the button, neither an error occurs, and also no data is transferred to the relevant data grid. How can I correct this?

Comment: Why are you creating new instance of `form` and why you are setting `GridView` `DataSource` multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add datarow to datatable after creating it.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr["MessageID"] = IDtext.Text;;
dr["Name"] = nameText.Text;
dr["Number"] = numberText.Text;
dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: the problem i face is each time the new dialog box appears when i press the button previously displayed data in the data grid gets deleted! how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general one , you can change according to ur need.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
        string str = txtname.Text.Trim();  
        string str1 = TextBox1.Text.Trim();  
        dt = (DataTable) ViewState["Details"];  
        dt.Rows.Add(str, str1);  
        ViewState["Details"] = dt;  
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;  
        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "Name";  
        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "Address";  
        GridView1.DataBind();  
    }
```

Comment: Don't use ViewState , its not needed here.